# OAuth2 `expires_in` Purpose

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

I'm working on incorporating an external api through OAuth and am a bit lost as to the purpose of the `expires_in` property. From reading around, api token use should be coded defensively in that you should expect that the token could be invalid at any point. If this is the case, what benefit does storing the expiry time have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your original point. By default ignore the expires_in field and reauthenticate and retry the API call with a new token if you get a 401. The expires_in field can be used as an optimization of required, but it does not properly deal with clock differences between client and server - or renewed token signing keys. Personally I never use expires_in.

Answer (score 0):

expires_in is for access token. It tells you that you have to refresh your token in X minutes. So it is the lifetime of your access token.

You also have a refresh token. Its lifetime is longer so you can request a new access token when it expires.

The access token can be invalided but in most cases you will only work with lifetime.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. While I understand this already, I'm sure it'll help others who come across this question! My question had more to do with the fact it seems to be best practise to assume the access token could be invalid at any point and so whenever it is being used, you should check if it's invalid. If you're always doing this check, I found `exipres_in` not very helpful. But as @Gary Archer points out above, `expires_in` can be used for optimisation in some cases.